# CodeIgniter: Inserting data into parent and child tables simultaneously

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a customer detail form. It's data will goto two tables `Snapshot` and `CustomerDetail`. CustomerDetail table has a foreign key refrencing `SnapshotPK`. SnapshotPK is an autoincrement column.

- How would I insert the data in both the tables when customer clicks on save button?
- Is it the option to in two insert statements inside a transaction which is `$this->db->trans_start()`. Wouldn't it affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use transactions. It's exactly the purpose for transactions - if one of the inserts fails, you can rollback the transaction. The performance hit is negligible to maintaining a consistent and clean database.